# What if I use cloudkit as a remote server for In-app Purchase? Any limitation imposed by Apple Inc.?

Tags: in-app-purchase, cloudkit

What if I use CloudKit as a remote server in lieu of my own server for In-app Purchase?  Any limitations imposed by Apple Inc.?
In order to improve the security I would like to use my own server for In-app purchase development but I found Cloudkit would be one of good candidates doing this.

For CloudKit itself has been designed to ease developer's effort in a specific way, I think that it might have some hurdles in using CloudKit as a remote server for In-App Purchase server.

I can not see any information regarding this from any documents contained in developer.apple.com.

Comment: Often people want to use a server to validate a purchase receipt. I don"t think you can do this with CloudKit.

Answer (score 0):

CloudKit is a data storage and notification service. What functionality did your own server do exactly? If your own server was just used for data storage, then you could do the same using CloudKit. With CloudKit you could use the iCloud account for filtering out data.

But then why do you want to save it on a server? You can use Storekit to put back/validate purchases. You should save the status of a purchase in the keychain. And if a user want your app to check his purchase status, then you should call Storekit.